# How to prove $\sqrt{x(3x+y)} + \sqrt{y(3y+z)} +\sqrt{z(3z+x)} \le 2(x+y+z)$

Tags: inequality, triangles, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove  $\sqrt{x(3x+y)} + \sqrt{y(3y+z)} +\sqrt{z(3z+x)} \le 2(x+y+z)$ using triangle inequality

To answer the comment: I'm pretty stumped on the question, i know i can substitute some variables in to make it simpler but from there im clueless, thats why im here, this is my last resort haha

Comment: Can you update your question to tell us what you've tried or what thoughts you have on the problem?

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{x(3x+y)}=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(3x^2+xy+2\sqrt{xy(3x+y)(3y+z)}}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(3x^2+xy+2\sqrt{x(3y+z)\cdot y(3x+y)}\right)}\leq$$
$$\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(3x^2+xy+x(3y+z)+y(3x+y))}=2(x+y+z).$$
Done!

The proof by triangle inequality (Minkowski).
$$2(x+y+z)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}(4x+3x+y)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{(4x)^2+0^2}+\sqrt{(3x+y)^2+0^2}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(4x+3x+y)^2+(0+0)^2}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{49x^2+14xy+y^2}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{48x^2+16xy+(x-y)^2}\geq\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{48x^2+16xy}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{x(3x+y)}.$$

Comment: is there a way to do it without using AM-GM because we havent covered that in our course, i need to use the triangle inequality

Comment: @Matthew Pronyshyn I used the following AM-GM: $2\sqrt{ab}\leq a+b$ for non-negatives $a$ and $b$. You can use it without words AM-GM because it's just $(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2\geq0$.

Comment: how could i do it using ||x+y|| $\le$ ||x|| + ||y||?